# Can't remove margins from page

Tags: html, css, margins

I am having trouble removing the side margins from the page I am building. I have tried setting the padding and margin to 0 with no success. Please see the attached picture and code. 
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SocialSweeper</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <?php 
            if (isset($_COOKIE['userData'])) {
        ?>
            <script>
                window.location.href = "explore.php";
            </script>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </head>

    <body>
```

CSS

```
@charset="UTF-8";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,700,400);

html, body {
    direction: ltr;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}
```

Comment: May you put your code in a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: where is the image?? lol

Answer (score 1):

Try this **CSS**:

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Pivemi, I have tried the above suggested code and it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check first the rendered code in browser by inspecting it (e.g. Right Click > Inspect [Elements Tab]).

Then click the `<body>` tag and see what are the CSS with it.

You can find out what causes the problem.

Finally, you can try the suggested CSS codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html, body {
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
}
```

EDIT:
or like pivemi already said:

```
* {
padding: 0 !important; 
margin: 0 !important;
}
```

with `!important`